# Scroll event in kendo editor

Tags: kendo-ui, editor

my problem you can see in the example below

It appears when you try to paste text from the clipboard

**HTML**

```
<div class="qqn" >
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <div id="sayHello"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.qqn {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.qqn > div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-right:10px;
  background: #222;

}
```

**js**

```
$('#sayHello').kendoEditor({
            tools: [],          
 })
```

Visit

http://jsfiddle.net/AT4XT/9/

Comment: May be old version bug, or not implemented 

https://jsfiddle.net/sc8tnutr/

seems allrigt on 2016

Comment: Please do not try and circumvent Stack Overflow's restrictions. You are more likely to get the question deleted than answered. Place the code into the question using the Code Snipped tool. That is what it is designed for. This way people can then answer you.